# Excel count recurrences of specific text within a date range

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use a formula to count how many times the text "JB" recurs in column J, but only count the recurrence's that fall within the current week. Logically in my head this translates to, count if date = current week AND text = JB.

The formula I currently have is:

```
=COUNTIFS(G4:G1109,">="&(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1), G4:G1109,"<="&(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+7), J4:J1105, "=JB")
```

But, quelle surprise, it doesn't work! Just returns a #VALUE! error.

Is there any way I can do what I want without using VB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data ranges are different heights. The SUMIFS() function requires all your ranges to be the same size. Try changing your formula to:

```
=COUNTIFS(G4:G1109,">="&(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1), G4:G1109,"<="&(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+7), J4:J1109, "JB")
```

(Note the change of J4:J1105 to J4:J1109)

Comment: That works great, thanks! Now one question, probably something not possible, imagine JB could also be Joe, is there a way to have an OR option on the last part?